# Why might the king want to break off from Seattle?

Tags: religion

In the holy lands of Seattle, where the great Kodiak is said to have meet his mortal martyrdom, the holy figure and leader of the Kodiakist religion resides. His name is Prophet Ground-Zero, and he is basically like a Pope in the catholic religion.

***About Kodiakism***

Kodiak the great was a mutant, the son of the god “ICBM” who smoted humankind with fire and fallout, and gifted a select few with a gift called “Mutation”. Kodiak gave his followers lessons about the world, and gave them great wisdom. He told them that humans were arrogant and unrighteous, and that mutants were overlords who would one day enslave them all. The lessons given by Kodiak promptly ended when he was betrayed by one of his followers Megaton, and beaten to death by some human scums.

Some of his followers, who by the names of Ground-Zero, A-Bomb, and Warhead, kept the religion alive, and know most Prophets of today use one of their names when they enter their papacy.

In the kingdom of Yakama, which is mostly loyal to Seattle, a new king has come to power. He wants to break off from Seattle, but I haven’t thought of a reason why he might. Why might the king want to break of from Seattle?

***About Seattle***

Seattle, or more formally “The Holy lands of Kodiak, the lands of Seattle” is a Theocracy lead by the Prophet and King, who is in the mid 25th century, Prophet Ground Zero, also known before as Cardinal Caza. There lands are in between Yakama and the Van (Former Vancouver). Van has a large trade economy, and the Seattle sees most of the profit from the trade, reselling it to Yakama.

Hey, I’m not completely sure about the rules, but can everyone give me time before voting to close my question. I want to try and fix it, and I don’t want it deleted and be forced to write to over

Comment: Hey, is this question ok or is it breaking a rule? I kinda feel like it’s breaking a rule but I’m not sure

Comment: Character motivations are broadly speaking your job, not WBs.  Your "new King's" motivations are defined by *you*.

Comment: The rule to check is [the "Too Story Based" rule](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened)

Comment: As stated, it's probably too broad and opinion-based - there are a *lot* of factors that could lead to a split like that. If you have a type of conflict in mind, that might help narrow things down. (The causes of, say, ethnic tensions in rebellion are different from economic stresses or the king just being ambitious, and they'll lead to different rebellions going forward.)

Comment: @StephenG: Ok, is their any way for me to fix it? Really need answers but can’t think of one myself

Comment: would be better if you put more details about the factions themselves, what would this king get out of breaking off. whats the risks, whats the gains the devil is in the details. telling us about the religion isn't helping that much. had a laugh over the names like a solder saying "lord Ground-Zero, A-Bomb and Warhead have taken the enemy castle"  the names could work but still funny

Comment: My view would be that history provides a *lot* of examples as to why leaders try to split off from larger groupings and you it's matter of choosing one that suits your needs.  When in doubt start with the Roman empire's history - it has pretty much everything.

Comment: Please see the [Why is my question "too story based"?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/why-is-my-question-too-story-based-and-how-do-i-get-it-opened) Meta question, we _can't_ do character motivations that's purely on the author.

Comment: If you want motivations for the King, read some Shakespeare. Pretty much any play at random will give you a whole lot of good motivations.

Comment: @user535733: Yeah, like king Henry the VIII. He did a something similar with the Catholic Church in Rome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Protestant Church Founding**

When religions begin to become too powerful they eventually begin to become corrupt and decadent at the expense of meeting the spiritual needs of the congregation. A great example was the catholic's selling indulgences to fund their obsession with building giant cathedrals, which themselves became huge cash-cows to build yet more cathedrals. People saw the catholic church essentially selling salvation to the wealthy while preaching to the poor that they had to suffer and strive for the same heavenly reward. It was pointed out by Martin Luther that the church itself had no actual authority over who received salvation and who didn't and argued that the church needed to ditch its money and power and focus more on its constituents actual spirituality. He even argued that perhaps priests weren't actually needed to commune with god.

Your church of mutant zealots has likewise become corrupt. Men with mere tumors or boils are paying the church of Kodiak for a guarantee that they will spend an eternity in the holy blue glow of Cerenkov's ionizing light in a blissful state of perpetual mutation while hard working poor mutants with extra arms and eyes are flogged and humiliated for the slightest transgressions. The church of Kodiak has strayed from the true essence of their founder in pursuit of profit and power. Kodiak was a simple wasteland warlord who espoused a meager life of raiding and a stoicism in the face of adversity. The new church parade around in expensive finery and jewelry preaching endurance in the face of adversity and stoicism with life's unpredictable challenges while not actually living such a lifestyle.

This has caused a schism in the church and this king has seized the opportunity to steal some wealth and power away from the true church by convincing people to convert to his new revivalist interpretation of the religion.

Comment: I like this answe, it’s pretty good. I like how it’s tied back to a historical event, in fact, I had planned for a Martin Luther like mutant to get the ball rolling

Comment: indeed even now the catholic church has problems with giving indulgences and feudal governments are self interest at heart most of the time so even if the Kodiakism church isn't corrupt brake away and rebellions under Theocracy's are not unheard of

Comment: Bear in mind that the reason a number of European monarchs embraced Protestantism had little to do with religion and more to do with power. Many monarchs saw adopting the new Christianity as an opportunity to get the Vatican off of their backs and hold more power and sovereignty within their own borders.